# Add Gaussian noise with C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

i want to add gaussian noise to input image with gaussian noise PDF(Probability distribution function) and i write this code and check many times but output is not correct,  i`m confused!

```
    int main() {
    Mat Frame;
    string address;
    printf("Please Drag and Drop Your Image");
    cin >> address;
    Frame = imread(address, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    int arrayOfIntensity[256] = { 0 }, intensity;

    //NEW COUNT INTENSITY OF EVERY PIXEL
    for (int i = 0; i < Frame.rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Frame.cols; j++) 
            arrayOfIntensity[Frame.at<uchar>(i, j)]++;

    //SUM OF INTENSITY
    int sumOfintensity = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Frame.rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Frame.cols; j++)
            sumOfintensity += Frame.at<uchar>(i, j);
    //AVG OF INTENSITY
    double avgOfintensity = sumOfintensity, varOfintensity = 0;
    avgOfintensity /= Frame.rows*Frame.cols;
    //VARIANCE OF INTENSITY
    for (int i = 0; i < Frame.rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Frame.cols; j++)
            varOfintensity += pow(Frame.at<uchar>(i, j) - avgOfintensity, 2);
    varOfintensity/= Frame.rows*Frame.cols;
    //PROBABILITY
    float probability[256] = { 0 }, intermediate[256] = { 0 }, factor, sumProb[256] = { 0 }, newSumProb[256] = { 0 };
    factor = (sqrt(6.28)*avgOfintensity);
    cout << "factor :" << factor << endl;
    factor = 1 / factor;
    cout << "new factor :" << factor << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        intermediate[i] =-1*(pow(i - avgOfintensity, 2))/(2 * pow(varOfintensity, 2));
        probability[i] = factor*(pow(2.718281, intermediate[i]));
        //SUM OF PROBABILTY
        if (i == 0)
            sumProb[i] = probability[i];
        else
            sumProb[i] = probability[i] + sumProb[i - 1];
    }
    //INTO 0-1 RANGE
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) 
        newSumProb[i] = sumProb[i]/ sumProb[255];

    float finalProb[256] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        double random = (rand() % 10) / 1000000.0 +(rand() % 10) / 100000.0 +(rand() % 10) / 10000.0 +(rand() % 10) / 1000.0 +(rand() % 10)/100.0+ (rand() % 10) / 10.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
            if (random<newSumProb[j]) {
                finalProb[i] = newSumProb[j];
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) 
        if (finalProb[max]<finalProb[i])
            max = i;

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        finalProb[i] =( finalProb[i] * 256.0 )/ finalProb[max];

    for (int i = 0; i < Frame.rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Frame.cols; j++)
            Frame.at<uchar>(i, j) = saturate_cast<uchar>(finalProb[Frame.at<uchar>(i, j)]);

    imshow("Result", Frame);
    waitKey();
}
```

correct output :
[tihs image is correct output with matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gCNn.jpg)
my incorrect output :
[this image is incorrect output with my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1ynY.jpg)

Comment: Did you try using the debugger, to see where your code deviates from your expectations?

Comment: yes and i check every output of every step! i guess cause of my problem is wrong algorithm.

Comment: Are you adding the noise in the right scale? I.e. is the image `0-1` or `0-255` and is the Gaussian noise in the same scale?

Comment: intensity of input image is between [0-255]. in this algo. there are 2 times normalized... one time sum of probability in every step normalized to [0-1], one time final probability for every intensity normalized to [0-255]...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, your code does not add Gaussian noise to the image.
Gaussian noise is defined by 2 values: the mean, and the std.

Adding gaussian noise to an image, means generating a new picture that is the size of the frame, where the distribution of the pixels' intensity follow a normal distribution, and then adding this to the actual image that you want to make noisy.

I haven't tried to completely understand your code, but what you are doing seems to be pixel dependent, and way more complicated than necessary.

To generate a frame of which pixels follow a normal distribution, you can use the central limit theorem, which states that summing n independent variables following the same distribution tends towards the normal distribution.

Hence, you can set each pixel of the frame to be:

```
/* Generate a pixel with a random intensity that follows the normal distribution */
int n = 30;
int sum = 0;
for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
    sum += rand() % 255;
pixel_i_j = sum / n;

/* 
 * pixel_i_j at this point follows a normal distribution with
 * parameters :
 *  - mean = 256/2 = 128
 *  - std = std of uniform law between 0 - 256 / sqrt(n)
 *
 * So adapt it to the normal law defined by my parameters */
pixel_i_j = ((pixel_i_j - mean) / std ) * my_std + my_mean;
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but after i edit my code is not working properly, but really change output(!) see this : http://s8.picofile.com/file/8275854300/a.png

Comment: Did you adapt it to follow your law? The distribution of the pixels before adaptation is, I believe but wikipedia will probably give you a better answer: 256/2 = 128 and std is 128 / sqrt(n). You need to make it so the mean is around 10 and the std less than that, so you keep a good signal to noise ratio.